# 'ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mvvm

I have been following a tutorial to create an MVVM prototype working in C#/Windows phone. This is my main. But the error I get is `ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel` is a `namespace` but is used like a `type`. Kindly assist me here. Thank you

```
namespace ExampleMvvmPhone
{ 
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**My xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFirstName" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Current.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Current.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtEmail" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="4"  Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Current.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="5"  Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Current.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**My ViewModel class:**

```
    namespace ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel
    {
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private List<Customer> customers;
        private int currentCustomer;

        //constructor
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.currentCustomer = 0;
            this.customers = new List<Customer>
            {
               new Customer
               {
                   CustomerID = 1,
                   Title = "Mr",
                   FirstName = "Mwangi",
                   LastName = "Austin",
                   Email = "mwangi@gmail.com",
                   Phone = "0728704660"
               },
               new Customer
               {
                   CustomerID = 2,
                   Title = "Mrs",
                   FirstName = "Christine",
                   LastName = "Nekunda",
                   Email = "mwangi@gmail.com",
                   Phone = "0728704660"
               },
               new Customer
               {
                   CustomerID = 3,
                   Title = "Ms",
                   FirstName = "Catherine",
                   LastName = "Nakutenga",
                   Email = "mwangi@gmail.com",
                   Phone = "0728704660"
               }
            };
        }

        public Customer Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customers[currentCustomer];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class has the same name as the namespace. Rename your class or use a fully qualified class name, e.g. `ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel.ViewModel viewModel = new ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel.ViewModel();`

Comment: I would rename the namespace to `ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModels` plural.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

Since you are in a different namespace, you should either include the namespace ViewModel defined in with `using`:

```
using ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel;
namespace ExampleMvvmPhone
{
...
```

or use add it to the class name:

```
ViewModel.ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the error is telling you exactly what your problem is:

> 'ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

If you look at your code, then you'll see that you *have* named your namespace and class name as `ViewModel`. Change this:

```
namespace ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModel
    {        ...
```

to this:

```
namespace ExampleMvvmPhone
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewModel` class, change your namespace  `namespace ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel` to only  `namespace ExampleMvvmPhone`. because if you use  `namespace ExampleMvvmPhone.ViewModel` for the `ViewModel` class then the compiler becomes confused whether `ViewModel` is a `class` or `namespace`.

Thanks